# Saving private key with certificate in keystore - Android

Tags: android, ssl, x509certificate, self-signed, android-keystore

I have gone through this question but couldn't really figure out why do we need it here. I have created a self-signed SSL certificate and testing it on my Android device. I have stored it in a `keystore` and use it like

```
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(context.getAssets().open("self.jks"), "password".toCharArray());


        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
```

It works fine i.e. I get correct response from server. My keystore looks like this

```
Keystore type: BKS
Keystore provider: BC

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: ca
Creation date: Apr 22, 2017
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=92.168.10.11,E=email@gmail.com,O=Self,L=Islamabad,C=PK
Issuer: CN=92.168.10.11,E=email@gmail.com,O=Self,L=Islamabad,C=PK
Serial number: f2b8e66caa28f0da
Valid from: Tue Apr 18 19:29:45 PKT 2017 until: Wed Apr 18 19:29:45 PKT 2018
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  2A:46:42:A8:7B:10:21:19:5F:B0:E2:A8:A1:BF:76:D3
     SHA1: 6A:18:AE:C7:4A:46:77:23:63:6B:8F:B8:40:46:49:47:67:30:5A:D5
     SHA256: B9:83:1A:D7:92:72:77:C2:88:AE:37:34:B4:70:31:94:C4:4E:03:7E:23:96:63:0C:00:E4:7F:35:B9:67:12:97
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256WithRSAEncryption
     Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

While the book I am following has keystore like following

```
Alias name: asynchronous_client
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=UK,ST=Birmingham,L=Birmingham,O=Packt Publishing,OU=Packt
Publishing,CN=asynchronous_client
Issuer: C=UK,…,CN=packt
Certificate[2]:
Owner: C=UK,…,CN=packt
Alias name: ca
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
Owner: C=UK,…,CN=packt
Issuer: C=UK,…,CN=packt
```

They have both **private key** and **certificate**. I want to know

> Why do they need private key here if everything works fine without it?
>   If we really need it, how will it be used in SSL handshake?

Comment: the communication scenario is not clear... the server presents a self-signed certificate, and you are shipping the server certificate in the android app, is that it?

Comment: Yes. I am just testing it. Is it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do they need private key here if everything works fine without it? If we really need it, how will it be used in SSL handshake?

The client doesn't need the server private key to perform an SSL handshake. It's not just unnecessary but also a security issue, because if anyone other than the server has a copy of the key, one can act on behalf of the server, e.g. a man-in-the-middle. A private key should not be with anyone other that its owner.

In this case, you should provide the client only with the server certificate (or a keystore containing it).

Comment: I thought the same but as it was in the book which confused me. I think I don't need to put certificate in the assets, I can download it from server too. Right?

Comment: @mallaudin actually, no. Try to access this site: https://self-signed.badssl.com/ and your browser will (or at least should) warn you. Why does it give a warning? because **a server presents an untrusted certificate, therefore the browser cannot attest that the server is who it is saying it is**. The same will happen to your app if you don't provide the certificate. The reason you provide the cert is that you are telling your app: **if the server provides this exact certificate, then the server really is who i am expecting it to be**

Comment: @mallaudin just out of curiosity: i edited the previous comment to mention you, and i'm not sure if you actually got a notification. Did you?

Comment: Yes. I mean is it really worth saving server certificate in a keystore in the app? I mean I can download it and set it for trust manager.

Comment: @mallaudin if your server certificate is not signed by any trusted CA (e.g. letsencrypt) then yes, it is worth. You also can download the cert in runtime, but you'll have another problem, that is to guarantee that the server you download the cert from is trustworthy. All of this is in the *public key infrastructure* context

Comment: Thanks @nan for your time.